# Is the deployment label used by the service?

Tags: kubernetes

I tried being more explicit when naming labels in a Kubernetes configuration file, thinking that deployments use the pod labels and services use the deployment labels.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
  labels:
    app: auth-depl-label
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-pod-label
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-pod-label
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: auth-pod
        image: bogdan-pechounov/auth
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-depl-label
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

However, `minikube service auth-srv` yields a `This site can’t be reached` error in Chrome. In the `minikube dashboard`, the service is pending and there are no pods associated with the service.

Using the pod labels instead does work, which makes me wonder what the deployment labels are for.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-pod-label
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

[full code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/microservices-quiz-app/tree/b7059b673266f7764f65f9c7402b4ce968031f13) (`skaffold dev` to start)

Comment: While not directly related to your question about labels, the minikube's Load Balancer is `Pending` because it is waiting for a "cloud provider" to provision a LoadBalancer, which is unlikely to happen in your minikube setup. Best to use a `NodePort` or other trickery when running outside of a cloud. That's a whole other can of worms, but using the search feature will show plenty of questions and answers about that, too, since it's so common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which makes me wonder what the deployment labels are for.

Every label is just a way to refer to a collection of resources without knowing their names. However, as you pointed out, kubernetes itself uses labels in a couple of ways related to your question:

- `Deployments` use labels for tracking the health and cardinality of their managed Pods (since the names of Pods are mostly random)
- `Services` use labels for tracking the Pods in `Ready` state to which traffic should be sent

With `Deployments`, one also needs to exercise caution that the `Deployment` object *itself* has labels, but those are not related to the `template: { metadata: { labels: {} } }` that are stamped onto newly created Pods and *those* are the ones which must be a subset of the `matchLabels:` for a `Deployment` to manage them

Same story with the `Service`, which again can have its *own* labels but are unrelated to the labels it uses for `Service` membership. Be aware that while it is super common to have the labels in `matchLabels:` be the same as those in the `Service`'s `selector:`, they otherwise have no relationship to one another

This is a perfectly fine setup, since the `Deployment` cares only about the Pods being `awesome` and the `Service` cares only about those Pods being `v1`, and both are fulfilled by newly spawned Pods from the Deployment because of the template's labels applied to them

```yaml
kind: Deployment
spec:
  ...
  matchLabels:
    app: awesome
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: awesome
        release: v1
---
kind: Service
spec:
  selector:
    release: v1
```